# PHP Loop to loop through page ID and locations

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to build a loop to show different location names based on the page ID. I am trying a for loop, but not sure how to get the 2 results, I tried a foreach, but still got lost.

```
$location = array(  "Frisco" => "1507",  "McKinney" => "1509");
$count = count($location);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if(is_page($location[$i])) {
        $location = "";
    }
}

Need results = 
    // Add Shortcode
    function dynamicLocation(){
    if(is_page('1')){
        $location = "McKinney";
    }
    else if(is_page()){
        $location....
    }
}
```

Comment: Your indexes aren't numeric. `$location[$i]` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget `for`, use `foreach`:

```
foreach ($location as $key=>$value){
    //here $key is the location and $value is the ID
    //e.g. $key="Frisco", $value="1507"
}
```